# How do I add the approve/reject button to the DisplayForm.aspx on a SharePoint 2013 task?

Tags: javascript, web-part, list-form, workflow2013

Hi I am attempting to add the approve/reject button to the DisplayForm.aspx (and possibly other forms) on a SharePoint 2013 task.

I have a custom SP 2013 workflow designed for streamlining an onboarding approval process for new consultants.  My intent is to make the approval process a bit more simplified so the "Approver" will not have to click on "Edit" or "Show More" when viewing an assigned task.

FYI, I do have access to SharePoint Designer 2013 but no InfoPath. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!